# Outlook email migration into SFDC case object

Tags: migration

We are migrating existing outlook emails i.e email related to open case into salesforce case object. Please provide me possible ways to migrate all emails into salesforce as email to case to create new cases in SFDC with email thread.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of is using this app from the app exchange [Email to Case Premium](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001R5cyEAC)